# Update from INNER JOIN specific ids but all were updated

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Currently, I am trying to implement a restaurant application. In DB I have `category` table and `item` table, one category must have many items and one item must have one category so this is a one to many relationships, I want to update some category records when a category hasn't any items that mean item if `qty on hand = 0` category `status` should be updated as `"deactivated"`  these are my tables

```
+-------+----------+-------------------+
| CatId | status   | catagory          |
+-------+----------+-------------------+
| C001  | Deactive | SeaFood           |
| C002  | Deactive | ITALIAN & western |
| C003  | Active   | Kottu             |
| C004  | Active   | Rice              |
+-------+----------+-------------------+


+--------+-------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------+
| ItemId | CatId | Price  | QtyOnHand | iteamName       | Date       | Time     |
+--------+-------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------+
| I001   | C003  | 650.00 |        30 | chease kottu    | 2020-04-26 | 19:55:59 |
| I002   | C003  | 650.00 |        25 | vgetable kottu  | 2020-04-26 | 19:55:59 |
| I003   | C003  | 450.00 |         3 | chicken koththu | 2020-04-27 | 08:32:12 |
+--------+-------+--------+-----------+-----------------+------------+----------+
```

this is the query that I  tried so far.

```
UPDATE catagory  INNER JOIN item  ON catagory.CatId = item.CatId SET catagory.`status` = "deactivated"
WHERE ((SELECT SUM(item.QtyOnHand)) >= 0);
```

this query updates all category `CatId` that have in the item table
as a beginner, for `MySQL`, I want some help.

Comment: There is `>= 0`  in the condition, this is not the same as "if qty on hand = 0"...

Comment: I also tried that  as  ```< 0 ```

Comment: But consider whether it's really sensible to store easily derived data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply add `where` clause inside your subquery and filter them as you want.
like this.

```
UPDATE catagory INNER JOIN item ON catagory.CatId  = item.CatId 
SET catagory.status ="deactivated"
WHERE (SELECT SUM(item.QtyOnHand) where catagory.CatId  = item.CatId GROUP By item.CatId) <= 0 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use update with join on subquery for catid having sum  = 0

```
    update catagory
    inner join  (
         select catagory.CatId,   SUM(ifnull(item.QtyOnHand,0)) tot
         from catagory 
         left join item ON item.CatId = catagory.CatId
         group by catagory.CatId
         having SUM(ifnull(item.QtyOnHand,0)) = 0
    ) t on t.CatId = catagory.CatId 
    set catagory.`status` = "deactivated"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE catagory
  INNER JOIN item  ON catagory.CatId = item.CatId
  SET catagory.`status` = "deactivated"
  WHERE COALESCE(SUM(item.QtyOnHand), 0) = 0;
```

Your `SELECT` inside the `WHERE` clause had no filtering. Also a `COALESCE()` was added to deactivate any category that has no items, too.